# The webserver could not be found for IIS-confugured Web Application Project

Tags: visual-studio, themes, dotnetnuke, iis-10, dnn9

When I am trying to create a new project in dotnetnuke 9 with for Theme develop using VS, I am getting the following error:

> "The Web Application Project is configured to Use IIs. The webserver  could Not be found "

I am using VS 2019 and SQL 2017. I create a website in IIS with port 80 that works correctly at localhost. Folder wwwroot/dnndev.me has Network Service permission full access, hostname is `dnndev.me` without `www`, there is no `.csproj` file because the project has not created it yet.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Ps: I use of "iisreset" comment at Run, but do not work for me.

Comment: Also run VS as administrator but do not work for me.

Comment: to resolve the issue open ii manager, select your site or application then click on the binding click on edit binding and add hostname dnndev.me to your bindings with port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have some virtual directories and/or applications in your web site. Visual Studio creates these very often when you open a project. It's safe to remove them - also after opening the project.